# How to detect a user's eye blinks with Google Glass builtin-sensors?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I want to use Google Glass to detect users eye blink rate, is that is possible using the built in sensors? How can I start with this?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, you can detect "winks" which requires user setup for what a "wink" is though, but there's no direct access to the IR sensor for detecting blinks (without "rooting")

Comment: there is a /GlassLogger on GitHub which shows the output of the IR sensor .

If I used it what I can do then ?

Comment: That sounds good, next you just learn what blinks are open look like using a classifier. *resurrecting question*

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can, you could use the glass libraries like:

```
import com.google.android.glass.eye.EyeGesture;
import com.google.android.glass.eye.EyeGestureManager;
import com.google.android.glass.eye.EyeGestureManager.Listener;
```

Here is an example project: https://github.com/thorikawa/EyeGestureLib